# CurrentUserDefault doesn't work using Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django / Django Rest Framework and I'm looking for a solution to insert the logged user id automatically.

i tried to use,  `user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())` :

But i doesn't work

This is my serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from contact.models import Contact

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

My View :

```
class ContactView(ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializeObject = ContactSerializer(data = request.data, many=True)
        if serializeObject.is_valid():
            serializeObject.save()
            contactObject = Contact.objects.all()
            contactSerializer = ContactSerializer(contactObject, many=True)
            return Response(contactSerializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializeObject.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Please show your view that uses this serializer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Can you double check my question please (updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `CurrentUserDefault` you need to pass the request in the `context` to your serializer as that is where the serializer will get the current user from. See [Including extra context [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

```py
class ContactView(ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializeObject = ContactSerializer(data = request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})
        ...
```